# Get the next (not immediatelly) element in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a structure of my HTML code like this:

```
<!-- First Step -->
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<!-- Second Step -->
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

I wanted to do that if one user press enter and the field is selected, it press automatically the Next input, and I make this jQuery code:

```
$('input[name="username"], input[name="password"]').keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
        $('input[name="next"]').click();
        return false;  
    }
});
```

It works, but only if the user press enter in the first step (in this case username). When the user try to press enter in the second step (in this case password) nothing happens because the code click the first input next of the page, in this case of the first step.

There's a manner with jQuery so the user can click the corresponding next button? I find the next function but it works only if it's the next sibling element.

Comment: hi can resolve issue by using unique name values , because its bad idea to have two element with same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thre are two button with `name=next` that is problem , because click enter on password it select first button which is `name=next`

Solution to problem is make use of [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function available in jquery libarary.

```
$( this ).parent().next('input[name="next"]').click();
```

---

another solution is make use of unique value for name vlaue,  **because its bad idea to have two element with same name**. try below  ex.

```
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="usernamenext" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<!-- Second Step -->
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="passwordnext" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

and you jquery be like

```
$('input[name="username"], input[name="password"]').keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
         $('input[name= "'+ $(this).attr('name') +'next"]').click();
        return false;  
    }
});
```

making use of unique will end all issues ,

Answer (score 0):

Use a traverse to target the specific instance and avoid clicking all of them

```
$(this).parent().next().click();
```